# translate the Escalated field into german

Tags: translation

on case object there is standard field is Escalated (which is checkbox type). I need to translate in German that is "Eskaliert" but the thing is its not found in Translation workbench and also not found in "Rename Tabs and Labels". how i can translate it into German language any luck

Comment: do you want to change a particular field or whole view of your screen to particular language?

Comment: @cloudZigZag, +1 you are definitely testing translations limit. Looks like it is cannot be translated, Its a standard field so only way to translate is from Rename Tabs and Labels setting. As an alternative you can create a formula field and translate it. I remember we did that for couple of fields as they were not available to translate.